# If $G$ is $k$-regular, then any connected component is $k$-regular

Tags: graph-theory

I'd like to know if this is enough to prove that:

> If $G$ is $k$-regular, then any connected component is $k$-regular.

Let $C$ be any connected component of $G$, if $C$ is not $k$-regular, then there exists a vertex $v\in V(C)$, $d(v)\neq k$. As $v \in V(G)$ too, then it would mean $G$ is not $k$-regular.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, what relationship is there between the degree of $v$ in $C$ and the degree of $V$ in G$?

Answer (score 1):

That's  false:

Consider $K_{4}$ and subgraph $1-2 , 2-3 , 2-4$

Comment: Yeah, but I'm talking about the connected components of the graph

Comment: and k4 it's the only connect component

Comment: @DanielaVelásquezGarzón the component that I mentioned is connected

Comment: yes but it's a subgraph, I think  I'm not giving my idea complete, let's say you have a graph G and G is $k_4 + k_2$ then $k_4$ is connected component of G and $k_2$ is other, when I say connected component I refer to that, no  to subgraph of G

Comment: Maybe the word it's subset of G?

Comment: @DanielaVelásquezGarzón but $k4+k2$ isn't a regular graph.

Comment: Yes, I Know but I'm trying to explain that when I say connectd component I mean to say in that example $K4$ or $K2$ so when you tell me that the subgraph $1-2, 2-3, 2-4$ from $K_4$ you are giving me an example of something I'm not refering to

Comment: @DanielaVelásquezGarzón I understand what does component mean. But regular graph has only one component for any $k$.